# Upload flash after build via IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

How to configure automatic upload of the generated flash file after it was built in IntelliJ IDEA via flex?

Before using IntelliJ IDEA I used a simple shell command to compile & upload the file. Now I want a similar process in IntelliJ IDEA.

```
mxmlc -debug=true -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true   -output flash.swf flash.as 2>&1 && scp flash.swf user@server:/var/www/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure external tool, for detailed instruction see [online help](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/external-tools.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using maven for many things that surround a Flex project.  In this case you could use one of these plugins:

[Maven FTP](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ftp.html)

or

[Cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin)